# How to export a function from single-spa util module and import the same function in single-spa micro front end?

Tags: micro-frontend, single-spa

I have the following 3 repositories.

root-config -> https://github.com/sravan464/web-root-spa

react mfe -> https://github.com/sravan464/mfe-react-1

vanilla utility module -> https://github.com/sravan464/single-spa-util-module-vanilla

I am trying to understand how to export a function from `single-spa vanilla utility module` and how can I import that function in my `react-mfe`
do we need to add a vanilla utility module in import maps of root-config ??

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your `root-config`'s `index.ejs`, seems the path towards the vanilla utility module is wrong:

Current in your `root-config` repository `index.ejs`:

> "@sravan-org/single-spa-util-module-vanilla":"//http://localhost:8081/sravan-org-single-spa-util-module-vanilla.js"

Correct one:

> "@sravan-org/single-spa-util-module-vanilla":"//localhost:8081/sravan-org-single-spa-util-module-vanilla.js"

You don't need to add "http://".